# Probability of cards using law of total probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

**Given two decks shuffled decks of 54 cards, split each in half (27 cards), then take one half of each deck and form a new deck of 54 cards. Then shuffle it and pick first two cards. Whats the probability of a match?**

I already know how to solve this problem using conditional probability, which is indeed simpler.

However, I want to develop some intuition on how to solve this problem using law of total probability. I added below the solution to this problem using conditional probability, but I tried to also solve using law of total probability but was unable to came up with a full solution.

**The real question here is: how to solve this using law of total probability?**

**My attempts so far use the following logic**: the probability of a match depend on how many pairs of cards are formed. So I tried to calculate each probability of exact number of pairs for each k=1, 2, ..., n/2 pairs, and then for each of those probabilities I multiply by the probability of picking a matching pair having k pairs in the deck. However the final probability does not seem to agree with my simulation.

The solution of this problem is easier if we use conditional probability as follows:

Start by observing that a match is only possible if the both come from different decks, as one deck has no repeated cards.

Define de event ${A: \text{both pick cards came from different decks}}$

Then find the probability of both cards coming from different decks. Notice that there is probability of 1/2 of taking the card from a specific half deck, since a card can come from each of the halves with equal probability.

Below $V_1$ means the first valued picked, and $V_2$ means second value picked.

$P(A) = P(V_1 \text{from deck 1})P(V_2 \text{from deck 2}) + P(V_2 \text{from deck 1})P(V_1 \text{from deck 2})  = 2 \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$

Now $P(V_1 = V_2| A) = 1/54$, then,

$P(V_2 = V_2) = P(V_1 = V_2|A)P(A) = 1/108$

How can we go about solving this without conditional probability?

Thanks

Edit: turns out this calculation using conditional probability is wrong, as the probability of cards coming from different decks is not 1/2. The probability of taking a card from, say, deck 1, changes when you pick a card from deck 2.

Correct probability is 1/106.

Comment: Why isn't it $1/107$?  After we pick the first card, the second card is equally likely to be any of the remaining $107$ cards, only one of which matches.  (The probability that the second card comes from the other pack than the first is $54/107$ not $1/2$.)

Comment: @saulspatz  Because, given the first draw, it is (slightly) more probable that the second draw will be from the other deck.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I meant to say "the other pack" not "the same pack".

Comment: @saulspatz  So, given the first draw, the second  has a probability of $\frac {27}{53}$ of being from the opposite deck.  Given than, the second has a probability $\frac 1{54}$ of matching the first which makes the answer the product $\frac {27}{53}\times \frac 1{54}=\frac 1{106}$.  I think.  Still having my morning coffee.

Comment: @lulu I don't think so.  After the first draw, there are $107$ cards remaining, $54$ from the other pack, so the probability should be $54/107$ rather than $54/106$.

Comment: @saulspatz  I thought the same thing at first, but the sorting process fixes the number drawn from each deck, that introduces a bias.  Consider the general situation with decks of size $N=2k$.  My formula yields $P(k)=\frac k{2k-1}\times \frac 1{2k}=\frac 1{2(2k-1)}$.  For $k=1$ the answer is clearly $\frac 12$, confirmed by the formula.   If your final deck were obtained by drawing $54$ cards uniformly at random from the original two decks, the answer would be $\frac 1{107}$.

Comment: @lulu I overlooked that part of the question completely!  I should learn not to come here before breakfast.  I still need to think about your answer, but I'll eat first.

Comment: Even I think it should be $\frac{1}{106}$.

Comment: I am not very clear on your conditional probability calculation. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There are not 108 cards. There are 54. And two decks of them. The probability should depend on how we split, not only on the total number of cards. Imagine in the extreme case you split 0 from one deck and 54 from other, then its zero chance of having a match.

Comment: You can also have zero matches if you combine two complimentary halves. So there seems to be more going on then just using the full number of cards.

Comment: @lulu I see it now.  Thanks.

Comment: All of the scenarios you are talking about gets considered when you say the probability that the next card could have come from the other deck is $\frac{27}{53}$.

Comment: @MathLover true. I will review the calculation on conditional probability. But the original question still remains the same.

Comment: @MathLover wait but two cards are picked at same time. So the probability is calculated as a pair. Thats why you don’t get any info from a first pick. I don’t know if it make sense, lol. The reasoning behind the conditional probability seems correct....

Comment: Pick together or one by one does not make any difference to the probability of them being from different decks. If you pick as a pair and that is how you want to write it then it is $\frac{27C1 \times 27C1}{54C2} = \frac{27}{53}$.

Comment: @MathLover true, when you pick a card from a deck you change the probability it comes from the other. So they are not independent events. If we set n=2 its clear. Then the probability of getting different cards is 1 and not 1/2 as I state in my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can solve this using the total law of probability.

Let $E$ be the event of a match, and let $X$ denote the number of matches in your newly formed deck of $54$ cards.

For $n\in \{0,1,2,\dots ,27\}$ we have $$P(X=n)=\frac{{54 \choose n}{54 - n \choose 27 - n} {27 \choose 27-n} }{{54 \choose 27}^2}$$ $$P(E|X=n)=\frac{n}{{54 \choose 2}}$$ From the total law of probability, $$P(E)=\sum_{n=0}^{27}P(E|X=n)P(X=n)=\frac{1}{106}$$

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to understand the combinatorials in the first equation. First $54 \choose n$ represents taking $n$ cards to form matches, which is, fixing $n$ cards. Then having those fixed, we can choose from the remaining $54-n$ cards to be any combination, so we choose $27-n$ from it. Now the last one is: we choose the cards to match the $n$ cards we fixed in the beginning. 
The denominator is just the total number of decks we can build from half decks. Is that correct?

Comment: You're right when you say the ${54 \choose n}$ term represents the $n$ cards we will choose to form matches. The ${54-n \choose 27-n}$ term represents the number of ways we can choose $27-n$ cards among the $54-n$ remaining cards in the first deck. So, at this point, we chose $27$ cards from the first deck and $n$ cards from the second deck. In order to ensure that we have only $n$ matches, we only have $27$ available cards to consider from the second deck, and we're choosing $27-n$ of them.

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying really hard to use this website to enhance my counting ability, and you're compliment means a lot. :)